# Why doesn't libstdc++ have span::span(Container&)?

Tags: c++, libstdc++, c++20, std-span, std-ranges

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/span), in C++20, `std::span` is supposed to be constructible using container references:

```
template <class Container>
constexpr span(Container& cont);
template <class Container>
constexpr span(const Container& cont);
```

but in the master branch of libstdc++'s [span](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/span) file (as of Jan 18th 2020), I don't see these constructors. I do see a constructor taking a `Range&&` - is that a sufficient replacement? Or - am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with C++ features that are in flux (such as for standards that aren't done yet), it's best to [go to the source](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/) rather than to secondary documentation like Cppreference.

At the time of this writing, [the working draft of the standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/span.cons#14) does what libstdc++ says: a single overload which can take a `&&` of a contiguous range. The restrictions on this function are similar enough to those from Cppreference that they're basically different ways of saying the same thing, but libstdc++ is implementing the standard as it currently exists.

Comment: I was mistakenly assuming that if cppreference and gsl::span had these ctors, so does the standard; and that std::span has been in the standard for enough time to not be in that much flux. But - I guess I was wrong.

Comment: @einpoklum: `span` *is* older than Ranges, but I’m not sure when the change was made.